# Postgresql password cannot login

Tags: postgresql

I typed the following instruction to set up the postgresql password.

```
sudo su - postgres
psql -U postgres
alter user postgres with encrypted password 'my_pass';
\q
sudo su - postgres
```

But I met the error.

> [sudo] password for postgres:my_pass
>
> Sorry, try again.

Which thing did I miss?

I actually set the password.

Thanks.

Comment: `alter user` is sql command while `sudo su - postgres` is OS - users are different for os and database. accordingly passwords are. use `passwd` for OS postgres password

Comment: edit question. leave only steps what you did and clearly defined goal please

Comment: So should I change into `alter user postgres with encrypted passwd 'my_pass';`? But I can't login to execute the statement.

Comment: what are trying to achieve? to set the password for os user or for db user?

Comment: I edited the question.I want to change the original os user postgres's password

Comment: Now I don't know the password fro postgres user.

Comment: hit `Ctrl+D` untill you get back to sudo user and then start over

Answer (score 11, accepted):

to change os user password, run sequentially:

`sudo su -`

`passwd postgres`

and enter a new password.

Keep in mind that if you are a sudo user, you wont be asked for a password anyway...

Comment: I am in a similar situation, however when I type "sudo su -" it asks me for postgres password...  any idea what I could do in this case?

Comment: because postgres is not sudo user. and you dont need `sudo su ` if you are postgres - just run `passwd`. Also if you are posttgres, why do U want to change the password? apparently you know it if you login...